# Windows Store: Page elements loading is jumpy, irksome

Tags: windows-store

I have a page with an Image on it, its source is a local .png asset. It loads into view in the most irksome manner.

It loads across the whole grid, like RowSpan="2" and then pops into place after a second or two. It's awful.

Demo from repro app based on new blank Store app.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="DeleteMeApp1.BasicPage1"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DeleteMeApp1"
    xmlns:common="using:DeleteMeApp1.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="Brown">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Assets/BackgroundTexturedBlackboard.png" />

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was down to the layout. Although technically legal, the arrangement doesn't work well.

I solved the problem by adding another Grid around the existing root one and making the new one the new root.

Into the new root I added the Image and the other elements I need to overlay the artwork and this ordering of elements renders better, although, with the transition effects I still need to tweak it.

**Update**

Actually, this isn't the end of the story. Removing the image and leaving just a rectangle with Opacity 0.5, the rectangle's opacity is set a second after the page has loaded. It's terrible.

I made a repro app, videoed the problem and submitted a connect bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792303/windows-store-xaml-atrocious-obvious-delayed-application-of-opacity#details